# Area of a surface by means of a double integral

Tags: real-analysis, surface-integrals

> Considering the surface in $\mathbb{R^3}$ given by:
>
> > $x^2-y^2=1$;  $x>0;-1<y<1;0\leq z \leq 1$

> Calculate its area by a double integral via a parametrization of the surface.

Firsly I setted up

$\phi:[0,\frac{\pi}{4}] \cup [\frac{7\pi}{4},2\pi] \times [0,1]$; $\phi(u,v)=(sec(u),tan(u),v)$

So, I have $2\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{\pi/4} ||\phi_u \times \phi_v||du dv$=$2\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{\pi/4} \sqrt{(sec^2(u))^2+(-tan(u)sec(u))^2}du dv$=$2\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{\pi/4} \sqrt{sec^4(u)+(sec^2(u)-1)sec^2(u)}du dv$=$2\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{\pi/4} \sqrt{2sec^4(u)-sec^2(u)}du dv$; but I haven't found an useful way to find the result. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the previous answer contained a mistake; the integral is not elementary as I'd initially suggested. Computing the area requires [elliptic integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#), specifically the incomplete flavors of the first and second kinds.

$$\begin{align*}
& 2 \int_0^{\tfrac\pi4} \sqrt{2\sec^4u - \sec^2u} \, du \\
&= 2 \int_0^{\tfrac\pi4} \sec^2u \sqrt{2 - \cos^2u} \, du \\
&= 2 \int_0^{\tfrac\pi4} \sec^2u \sqrt{1 + \sin^2u} \, du \\
&= \sqrt6 - 2 \int_0^{\tfrac\pi4} \frac{\sin^2u}{\sqrt{1+\sin^2u}} \, du & \text{(by parts)} \\
&= \boxed{\sqrt6 - 2E\left(\frac\pi4,i\right) + 2F\left(\frac\pi4,i\right)} \approx 2.199
\end{align*}$$

The last line follows from the definitions for $E,F$ upon splitting up the integrand as

$$\frac{1+\sin^2u-1}{\sqrt{1+\sin^2u}} = \sqrt{1+\sin^2u} - \frac1{\sqrt{1+\sin^2u}}$$